# Arrows to show log to exponential

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

I am needing to show arrows in a "circle" to demonstrate converting logarithms to exponentials and vice versa as the images show:

[image: log to exponential]

[image: exponential to log]

I have tikz called, but have had no luck with getting the arrows lined up correctly. In particular, I need an arrow going from the logarithm base to the other side of the equal (and one from a variable to the power of an exponent).

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, as you have already it is possible via TikZ. However, could you show us what you have tried so-far? because, please note that this is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site.

Comment: @Gregory You may want to use the [tikzmark](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-this-for-me` question.

Answer (score 6):

As frougon mentions, the `tikzmark` package can be used here. (Notice that there were some versions with a little bug around so you may just have to hit enter if you get errors in the first run. In the subsequent runs these errors will be gone.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\tikz[baseline={(nd.base)},nodes={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},remember picture]{
 \node(nd){$\subnode{y}{y}=\log_{\subnode{b}{b}}(\subnode{x}{x})$};
 \draw[-{Latex[bend]},shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt](y.north) to[out=80,in=100]
 node[midway,above=1pt,font=\sffamily\tiny]{equals} (x.north);
 \draw[-{Latex[bend]},shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt](x.south) to[out=-100,in=-70]
 node[midway,below=1pt,font=\sffamily\tiny]{the power of} (y.south);}
 means $b^y=x$

\medskip
\tikz[baseline={(nd2.base)},nodes={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt},remember picture]{
 \node(nd2){$\subnode{b2}{b}^{\subnode{y2}{y}}=\subnode{x2}{x}$};
 \draw[-{Latex[bend]},shorten <=2pt](x2.north) to[out=100,in=80]
 node[midway,above=1pt,font=\sffamily\tiny]{equals} (y2.north);
 \draw[-{Latex[bend]},shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt](b2.south) to[out=-80,in=-100]
 node[midway,below=1pt,font=\sffamily\tiny]{log of} (x2.south);}
 means $y=\log_b(x)$
\end{document}
```

[image]